# Text not showing (beginner)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm a beginner in Java, learned a few things and decided to try it out. I've so far coded in C++ for over a year and I've noticed some similarities in java coding so far. I'm used to simply hand the elements of a string by passing the string's name and the element that I want to show (i.e: string[i]="a"), being pretty simple but, in java, I've encountered some problems in passing the string and its position to some fragments (using a viewpager).
Simply put, I can't seem to show any text on my fragment. I'm aware that my coding is chaotic but I'd really appreciate any help.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String [] sir = new String[500];
        for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            sir[i] = "This is Fragment " + i;
        }

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), sir);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            }

        });
    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private String [] sir;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String [] stringstodisplay) {
            super(fm);
            this.sir = stringstodisplay;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 500;
        }


    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private String mText; // display this text in your fragment

        public static Fragment getInstance(String text) {
            Fragment f = new Fragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("sir", text);
            f.setArguments(args);
            return f;
        }

        public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
            super.onCreate(state);
            setmText(getArguments().getString("sir"));
            // rest of your code
        }

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummyfragment, container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(getArguments().getString(mText));
            return rootView;
        }

        public String getmText() {
            return mText;
        }

        public void setmText(String mText) {
            this.mText = mText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any kind of error or do you just get to the dummy fragment with no text?

Comment: No, I don't get any error, it compiles and runs smoothly. I simply don't have any text on my fragment.

Comment: Try testing to see if the string is actually making it to the fragment in question. You can make it print the string to the console with the Simple debugging LOG or System.out.println(getmText()). This will just show you that the string is being passed around correctly.

Comment: There is an example app/source code on commonsguy's github that achieves exactly what you are attempting to do if you wanted to take a look. Link: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Fragments/src/com/commonsware/android/pager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`dummyTextView.setText(getArguments().getString(mText));`

with

`dummyTextView.setText(getmText());`
 

or


`dummyTextView.setText(getArguments().getString("sir"));`

This should work.

Comment: I've thought of both of these before and tried them once again just now. None worked, unfortunately. (In case I wasn't clear enough, the text that I want to be showed on my fragment would be "This is Fragmet" + the position of the fragment (as in the example,  for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            sir[i] = "This is Fragment " + i;)

Comment: The issue I see is you are not using getInstance() to initialise the fragment. So you have to use `setmText("" + getArguments().getInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)); ` in `onCreate`

Comment: Right, I new get to see the position of each fragment on the screen represented by a number due to the arguments setmText. What should I replace the "" in setmText("" + getArguments().getInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)); in order to be able to hand the string array sir too? Becasue in the end that's the one I want to appear on the screen.

Comment: Replace `Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();` with `Fragment fragment = DummySectionFragment. getInstance("" + (position + 1));` .  Also change ` Fragment f = new Fragment();`  to ` Fragment f = new DummySectionFragment(); `